# Need to write a resource based policy on secrets manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, aws-secrets-manager

I need to write a resource based policy for my secret manager so that its secret can be seen or change by a specific role only via the cli.

```
{
      "Version" : "2012-10-17",
      "Statement" : [ {
        "Effect" : "Allow",
        "Principal" : {
          "AWS" : "*"
        },
        "Action" : "secretsmanager:*",
        "Resource" : "*",
        "Condition" : {
          "StringEquals" : {
            "AWS:SourceOwner" : "xxx/role"
          }
        }
      } ]
    }
```

I am doing this in my serverless.yml as:

```
 xxResourcePolicy:
      Type: "AWS::SecretsManager::ResourcePolicy"
      Properties:
        SecretId:
          Ref: xxSecretsManager
        ResourcePolicy:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Resource: "*"
              Action:
                - "secretsmanager:*"
              Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                AWS: "*"
              Condition:
                StringEquals:
                  AWS:SourceOwner: !Ref "AWS::AccountId"
```

Also I would like to know whats the best possible way to upload the keys first time in secret manager.
Should I encrypt the keys .I am new to it and dont know much about this.

I am currently reading like this the direct value from a file:
SecretString: '{"app-public-key":"${file(./ok-creds-${opt:stage}.yml):APP_PUBLIC_KEY}"'